# accept self-signed SSL Certificates-> where to set default TrustManager

Tags: android, http, ssl, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

First I had to admit that I know that accepting all certs can be considered as having no security. We have "real" Certs but only on our live systems. The certs on our test systems are self-signed. So as long we're developing, we have to use test-servers, which forces me to kind of disable certificates.

I saw a lot of toppics here on Stackoverflow and all over the web which are all trying do do the same: 
Accepting SSL Certificates. However None of these answers seem to apply to my Problem, as I'm not messing with `HTTPSUrlConnections`.

If I'm doing a request the code usually looks like this (commented for clearification):

```
//creates an HTTP-Post with an URL
HttpPost post = createBaseHttpPost();
//loads the request Data inside the httpPost
post.setEntity(getHttpPostEntity());
//appends some Headers like user-agend or Request UUIDs
appendHeaders(post);

HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
//mResponse is a custom Object which is returned 
//from the custom ResponseHandler(mResponseHandler) 
mResponse = client.execute(post, mResponseHandler);
return mResponse;
```

I read that I should inject my own `TrustManager` and `X509HostnameVerivier`. I created them like this:

```
private static final TrustManager[] TRUST_ALL_CERTS = new TrustManager[]{
        new X509TrustManager() {

            public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return new X509Certificate[]{};
            }

            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType)
                    throws CertificateException {
            }

            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType)
                    throws CertificateException {
            }
        }

    };

    private static X509HostnameVerifier ACCEPT_ALL_HOSTNAMES = 
            new X509HostnameVerifier() {

                public void verify(String host, String[] cns, String[] subjectAlts)
                        throws SSLException {
                }

                public void verify(String host, X509Certificate cert) throws SSLException {
                }

                public void verify(String host, SSLSocket ssl) throws IOException {
                }

                public boolean verify(String host, SSLSession session) {
                    return true;
                }
            };
```

If I inject the `HostnameVerifier` inside my request like this (client is DefaultHttpClient from above)

```
SSLSocketFactory ssl = (SSLSocketFactory)client.getConnectionManager().getSchemeRegistry().getScheme("https").getSocketFactory();
ssl.setHostnameVerifier(ACCEPT_ALL_HOSTNAMES);
```

the response turns from "hostname ** didn't match" to "Bad request". I guess I have to set the TrustManager, but I'm clueless where to set it inside my request, as I'm not using HttpsUrlConnections mentioned everywhere I looked it up.

Comment: Instead of adding code that lets any cert through (which is code that might never be removed, especially if you forget about it when the deadline comes), you could consider running your own test CA. You'd have to import that test CA cert in the trust store, but that's a more realistic test, including with host names (and less prone to leaving bad code in the released product). There are tools to help you manage small CAs.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, it doesn't force you to disable validation, it forces you to implement validation properly. *Do not* blindly accept all certificates. And no, your case is not any different, you just need to trust a certificate that Android doesn't trust by default.

You are using HttpClient, so the APIs for setting the trust manager are somewhat different than `HttpsURLConnection`, but the procedure is the same:

1. Load a keystore file with trusted certificates (your server's self-signed certificates)
2. Initialize a `KeyStore` with it.
3. Create a `SocketFactory` using the `KeyStore` from 2.
4. Set your HTTP client library to use it when creating SSL sockets.

This is described in Android's documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/conn/ssl/SSLSocketFactory.html

A more detailed article on the subject, shows how to create the trust store file: http://blog.crazybob.org/2010/02/android-trusting-ssl-certificates.html

Some background information and example code: http://nelenkov.blogspot.com/2011/12/using-custom-certificate-trust-store-on.html

This is the code you need to initialize HttpClient:

```
KeyStore localTrustStore = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
InputStream in = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.mytruststore);
localTrustStore.load(in, TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD.toCharArray());

SchemeRegistry schemeRegistry = new SchemeRegistry();
schemeRegistry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory
                .getSocketFactory(), 80));
SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = new SSLSocketFactory(localTrustStore);
schemeRegistry.register(new Scheme("https", sslSocketFactory, 443));
HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
ClientConnectionManager cm = 
    new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(params, schemeRegistry);

HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(cm, params);
```

At this point, you have no excuses for trusting all certificates. If you do, it all on you :)